# How to exclude raw from result set in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

I was Reading About **SQL-Injection** in **SQL-Server** and i saw an Technique That allow me to show any information from database via **Errors**

assume this is  the vulnerable site:

```
www.victim.com/showproducts.aspx?category=bikes
```

and when i put this code after parameter value :

```
www.victim.com/showproducts.aspx?category=bikes AND 1=0/username
```

this will show an Error that told me its can do an / via int and string and get an data from column username .

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'admin' to data type int
```

its show me the **first data** in **column username** , etc : **admin**
when i try to get another username i exclude the fist value 'admin' via :

```
www.victim.com/showproducts.aspx?category=bikes AND username not in ('admin') AND 1=0/usernaame;
```

but its still get the first value " admin " , . why ? and how to get the next value from this technique ...

Comment: Why are you trying to inject into a website in the first place? The better answer is to fix the code on the website/SP to stop the injection.

Comment: @Larnu im trying to understand the idea about sql injection attacks so i save my sites .

Comment: Using [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) goes a long way to protecting against SQL Injection attacks. As for analysing the results you are seeing, debug your code or use SQL Server Profiler to see what SQL is actually being executed.

Comment: @Diado , ok i will thanks , but can you answer my question why its still get me the first value and im exlude it from result set ?

Comment: Not without seeing your code, no

Comment: @Diado select id,username,password from users where id = 1;

Comment: That SQL can't be injected into; it's not got any text concatenation.

Comment: Also, are you ***really*** storing user passwords as plaintext? You should really be storing it as a hashed and salted value.

Comment: @Larnu , the error will show the data , and i already said im try to understand the sql injection .

Comment: There isn't any. That's my point. you can't inject into the statement `select id,username,password from users where id = 1;` There's no where for injection to take place. Injection normally takes place when using string concatenation to in the application with parameters, or the generation of dynamic SQL with parameters when they aren't quoted or aren't passed as a parameter themselves to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Also, if (from details we don't know yet) the application is open to injection, and you (the website) ***are*** storing passwords as plain text (you didn't respond to that comment) I have no interest in telling you how to inject; I would hate to cause some user's password to be compromised due to my advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear what the OP is really trying to achieve. We are also lacking the code to reproduce the issue. It appears, as well, that the application is storing passwords in plain text; a concern as that is a disaster waiting to happen with injection. I would hate for any of the user's here to provide advice that leads to OP committing injection on a application they have limited access to (including passwords).

Comment: anyone know the answer please ? im waiting ..

Comment: If you address the comments, and post the code (like we've asked), I'll be happy to try and help still (even after your previous comment), but otherwise my points stand. We can't see what you see, so we need more detail to be able to answer. If you can't/won't share that information, we can't help. Help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu ok bro im sorry, but i read it from book and i try to tested it in sqlserver mangmanet , and i just create table users and 3 columns ;id,username.password and try to inject it , the only statement is : select id,username,password from users where id = 1 ; just , and i try to do an injection after the parameter 1 , " where id =1 AND inject here " , its clear now ?

Comment: Not really. Post the code you're using the run the SQL in your application. make sure you edit your post, please don't post it in the comments.

Comment: @Larnu i cant provide images , thats what the site tell me when i try to add images .

Comment: Why are you trying to post images? Code is text.